# Firma digital XML

Tags: xml, firma-digital

Buen dia amigos,

Estoy intentando armar una factura electronica, pero en el sector de la firma me pide el DigestValue, pero no se como generarlo, alguien sabe que es lo que debo colocar ahi, muchas gracias.

```html
 <xades:SigningCertificate>
 <xades:Cert>
 <xades:CertDigest>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
<ds:DigestValue>  </ds:DigestValue> <!--Buscar-->
</xades:CertDigest>
 <xades:IssuerSerial>
<ds:X509IssuerName>C=CO,L=Bogota D.C.,O=Andes SCD.,OU=Division de certificacion entidad final,CN=CA ANDES SCD S.A.
Clase II,1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=#1614696e666f40616e6465737363642e636f6d2e636f</ds:X509IssuerName>
<ds:X509SerialNumber>5baa826812650bcc</ds:X509SerialNumber> <!--Puede ser o no el valor-->
</xades:IssuerSerial>
</xades:Cert>
</xades:SigningCertificate>
```

Answer (score 1):

parece que tu ejemplo es un extracto de un archivo xml más completo, correcto? Porque los archivos xml con firma digital según XADES tienen varios campos de DigestValue, si no estoy equivocado.

De todos modos, para tu ejemplo específico, se trata del DigestValue del certificado que acompaña o más bien que se incorpora en tu archivo, como parte de la firma (si es una firma tipo enveloped) o que incluye alguna referencia externa al certificado. Para obtener el DigestValue del certificado, haces lo siguiente:

```
$certificado = 'MMIdhsuesHG...'; // las letras serán completamente diferentes en tu caso. Es tu certificado x509, sin "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" y "-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
$hashCertificado = hash('sha1', $certificado, TRUE);
// sha1 porque tu misma referencia lo indica (DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"
// TRUE porque necesitamos que el hash sea binario para el siguiente paso
$digestCertificado = base64_encode($hashCertificado);
// lo que está en $digestCertificado es lo que estás buscando
```

Lo que pones más abajo como "Puede ser o no el valor" tiene que ser el número de serie del certificado; nada que ver con el DigestValue. El número de serie está entre las propiedades del certificado, al igual que los datos de emisor que pusiste en la línea anterior (X509IssuerName).

Comment: me gustaria contactarme contigo para unas dudas sobre XADES-EPES !... se puede ?

Comment: En lo que le puedo ayudar, con mucho gusto - adelante.

Comment: podrias pasarme tu contacto ?, mi correo es: siegroupmx [a] gmail com